# sqlite3 bind variables syntax

Tags: c++, c++11, sqlite, parameter-passing

I am trying to implement a C++11 wrapper to C API of SQLite, particularly to sqlite3_bind functions. I would like it to be something in the shape of this (example from my code):

```
sqlt3::exec<void>(
    _db,
    "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO window VALUES('position', ?3, ?4);\n"
    "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO window VALUES('size', ?1, ?2);\n"
    "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO window VALUES('maximized', ?5, '0');\n",
    size.x,
    size.y,
    position.x,
    position.y,
    static_cast<int>(IsMaximized())
    );
```

The problem here is that `?` are shared between different statements. The `exec` function internally prepares subsequent SQL statements one by one. So I cannot determine which parameters should be bound to which statements, because there is no API to get which statement slots the statement contains. I can get the count of slots `n` (a max NNN from all ?NNNs) but I am unable to determine whether particular slots from zero to the `n` are actually occupied. It is because there can be single `?` with no number and `sqlite3_bind_parameter_name` returns `NULL` for both the nameless parameter and the lack of parameter. Ideally I would like to have some function that returns a list of indexes of binding points that are used in the given statement or at least some way to discriminate whether given index has associated 'nameless' binding point or no binding point at all.

One solution that I came upon is to bind all parameters, in the order they are passed to the `exec`, to all of the statements but I didn't found in the documentation is it legal to bind to nonexistent parameter. Another drawback is that the complexity is `v` times `s` where `v` is number of variables to be bound and `s` is number of statements.

So, I came with another workaround to just parse whole string passed to `exec` and gather info about binding points (`?`, `?NNN`, `:VVV` etc.). But, I think it isn't quite trivial task because that special symbol are not special in some contexts like string and quatations. So, what are another contexts in SQL statements, in which special tokens `?`, `?NNN`, etc. have not meaning of binding points?

**Some explanations:**

"Trying to parse SQL is pointless."

I do not want to parse SQL, only detect presence and indexes of arguments (binding points).

"Do you really think v*s will become large enough that it matters?"

In common case no, but still I do not know if it is legal to bind parameter to slot that wasn't occurred in statement. And there is a problem with `?`, if it occurs at the beginning of second sentence, it should not has index 1, it should rather have index of the last binding point in previous sentence increased by 1.

"And why do you want to allow multiple statements in a single function call?"

I found ability to do that very handy, especially when you need to execute them in one transaction.

Comment: Trying to parse SQL is pointless. Do you really think `v*s` will become large enough that it matters? And why do you want to allow multiple statements in a single function call? And how would it differentiate between an SQL statement and a string parameter?

Comment: @CL I've added answers to your questions to the main post. And could you clarify last question because I don't get it?

Comment: `exec("INSERT INTO t VALUES(?)", "INSERT INTO t VALUES(?)")`: is this one statement and one parameter?

Comment: @CL Notice the there is no commas after particular statements in my example. The string with SQL statements is always passed in whole as second argument. So in your above example the second argument is a parameter.